# How can I set a callback to an asynchronous HTTP service in Angular so that I can fill my array in my controller without it being undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, asynchronous, callback

**How can I set a callback to an asynchronous HTTP service in Angular so that I can fill my array in my controller without it being undefined?**

**My Code:**

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']); //create module

    app.factory("Rest", ['$http', function($http){ //create service factory
        var allUsers = []; //initialize empty allUsersArray
        return{
            getUsers: function(doneCallback){ //getUsers function with a callback parameter
                var getHttp = $http({ //GET request from my test.json
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'test.json'
                });
                getHttp.then(function successCallback(response) {
                    var users = response.data;
                    for(var i = 0; i < users.people.length; i++){
                        allUsers.push(users.people[i]); //add the objects to the allUsers array at the top
                    }
                    console.log("This is from within the SERVICE: " + allUsers[1].first); //showing that I can access the allUsers array within the service.

                    doneCallback(response.data.people); //my sad attempt to call this in the controller and still ended up being undefined.

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    console.log("Error!");
                });
            }
        }

    }]);

    app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'Rest', function($scope, Rest){
        $scope.usersArray = [];
        //when the get request is completed fill in the $scope.usersArray
        $scope.addUsers = function(users){
            for(var i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
                $scope.usersArray.push(users); //trying to add the users from the SERVICE to the CONTROLLER $scope.usersArray[]
            }
            console.log("This is from within the CONTROLLER: " + $scope.usersArray[1].first); //showing up as undefined :(
        }
        Rest.getUsers($scope.addUsers);
        //$scope.getUsers = Rest.getUsers;
    }]);
```

**index.html** (nothing special because were looking in the console for the correct response from my updateUser.php)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Restful Test</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <h1>Welcome to REST Test!</h1>
</body>
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</html>
```

**updateUser.php**

```
<?php 
    $use = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    for($i=0; $i < count($use->users); $i++){
        var_dump($use->users[$i]->first . " " . $use->users[$i]->last . " is a " . $use->users[$i]->position);
    }
?>
```

**test.json**

```
{
    "people": [
        {"first": "Edward", "last": "Smith", "age": 18, "position": "Accountant"},
        {"first": "Lucas", "last": "Santos", "age": 23, "position": "Programmer"},
        {"first": "Jeremy", "last": "Grey", "age": 27, "position": "Fire Fighter"}
    ]
}
```

So I tried keeping my code as simple as can be just for testing purposes and for the sake of this question.

My problem that I am having is that in order for me to manipulate my JSON data being pulled in with the Angular's $http service GET method I would first need to have it accessible within the controller so then I can update it and do whatever I want to it from within the controller. But now the problem is that the $http call is asynchronous and does not get the JSON before it needs to populate **$scope.usersArray** within the controller therefore making it **undefined**.

So I tried making a callback function called **doneCallback** which fires within the **$http.then** method which is suppose to promise it to be completed before firing the callback function. For some reason it is not and the array within the Controller that I am trying to fill is still undefined no matter what.

Comment: you can use $q service of angularjs

Comment: Your main issue is `$scope.usersArray.push(users)`. That should probably be `$scope.usersArray.push(users[i])` but see my answer below for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply return a promise from your `Rest` service, eg

```
app.factory("Rest", ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getUsers: function() {
            return $http.get('test.json').then(function(response) {
                // the return value of this promise chain...
                return response.data.people || [];
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.usersArray = [];
Rest.getUsers().then(function(people) {
    console.log(people);

    // to push all the new "people" into the array...
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.usersArray, people);
});
```

See [*"Merging two arrays"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Merging_two_arrays)

Comment: whoa ok so I tried your way and my way but with the [i] that I was missing and they both work. So the callback I tried worked after all but your way seems like the best way if I am not mistaken

Comment: Hey I do not understand the part in the controller where is says `.then(function(people) {}` how does the then promise know that the people parameter is from my returned data in the service?

Comment: The promise returned from `Rest.getUsers` is resolved with `response.data.people`. The `then()` in your controller is passed that value when the promise resolves

Comment: I see ok thank you for your answer really appreciate it the help.